# How add VCS access in intellIJ menu?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, version-control

I recently switched from VS Code to IntellIJ Ultimate.
I was wondering what is the equivalent of Version control for IntellIJ and found out about "version control" which should be accessible in the menu.

I don't have this tab visible in the menu.
This is a screen of my settings. How could I add it to my menu ?

[image: screenshot of settings from Intellij]

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE to check configuration?

Comment: @y.bedrov This is a huge file, I can't paste the whole content in my post. What part should I focus on?

Comment: Actually you could check it for errors/warnings. You may use any online sharing service.